# Error with Long datatype in java

Tags: java

Actually my system gives Long.MAX_VALUE as 9223372036854775807

But when I write my program like this,

```
package hex;

/**
 *
 * @author Ravi
 */
public class Main {

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO code application logic here

        long x = 9223372036854775807;

        System.out.println(x);

    }

}
```

I am getting compile time error. Can anyone explain the reason?

Comment: `long x = 922337203685477580L`

Comment: @user650521 You don't want answers for you new questions, do you? If one of these answer has been helpful - and I think it was - why don't you click on the outlined ✓ check mark on the left?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

With no suffix, it's an int constant (and it overflows), not a long constant.  Stick an `L` on the end.

Answer (score 4):

You might want to try using like this:

```
long x = 9223372036854775807L;
```

Without the **L** at the end, you'll be declaring an `int`.

Answer (score 3):

`9223372036854775807` is an `int` literal, and it's too big to fit in an `int`.
The fact that yo assign the `int` literal to a `long` makes no difference.

You need to create a `long` literal using the `L` suffix.

Answer (score 0):

if you don't specify what kind of number literal is, then `int` is assumed. You need to specify that you want `long` by adding "l" or "L" (better, because "l" looks like 1) at the end of the number:

```
long x = 9223372036854775807L;
```

instead of:

```
long x = 9223372036854775807;
```